# Java - Generating a list of every permutation of 4 characters

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, syntax, char

I'm trying to generate a list of all possible 4 characters permutation of the first 4 letters of the alphabet (i.e. aaaa, aaab, aaac, aaad, aaba...) I figured I'd go with nested for loop, but when I run the program, the for loops seem to be skipped altogether and I only see the "Number of chain printed 0"

What am doing wrong?

```
package com.company;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String suite = new String();
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            char[] table = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
            char c1;
            char c2;
            char c3;
            char c4;
    
            int total = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j == 3; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k == 3 ; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l == 3; l++) {
                        for (int m = 0; m == 3; m++) {
                                   c1 = table[j];
                                   c2 = table[k];
                                   c3 = table[l];
                                   c4 = table[m];
                                   suite = Character.toString(c1) + Character.toString(c2) + Character.toString(c3) + Character.toString(c4);
                                   list.add(suite);
                                   System.out.println(suite);
                                   total++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of chain printed " + total);
            }
    
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to initialize `suite` with `new String()`; you are never using that empty string. Further, `suite = Character.toString(c1) + Character.toString(c2) + Character.toString(c3) + Character.toString(c4);` is unnecessarily complicated. You can simply use `suite = "" + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your looping conditions are incorrect; it should be `<= 3`, not `== 3`, which would make the loop only continue as long as the counter is equal to 3—the loop will never even start in that case.

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k <= 3 ; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l <= 3; l++) {
             for (int m = 0; m <= 3; m++) {
```

Comment: omg, I feel so dumb, thanks!

Comment: @Titobaube No problem.